# Best database collation for multilanguage site

Tags: 6, database, i18n-l10n

I’m running a  Multilanguage site (drupal 6) using  both: Latin language and  a no-Latin language characters.

Before the install. I used  phpmyadmin,  to change the default MySQL connection collation, from latin1_swedish_ci  to utf8_general_ci.
wondering if I'm doing things right? Or should I leave the  default MySQL  collation in latin1_swedish_ci ?

Comment: The detailed answer [over here][1] may help you in making a decision.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036454/what-are-the-diffrences-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci

Comment: utf8_unicode_ci seems to be the best option

Comment: The link shared by @Arosboro is good but I found this post on stackoverflow very helpful with a detailed discussion of [the differences between utf8_unicode_ci and utf8_general_ci](http://stackoverflow.com/a/766996/1048805). A subsequent answer also contains a [performance analysis between the two](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15170166/1048805).

Answer (score 1):

utf8_general_ci is preferred over latin1_swedish_ci

The good news is that as a result of this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/772678) Drupal now defaults to utf8 so no one should have to worry about this any longer. This fix has been backported to Drupal 6 so this answer should be applicable to Drupal 6, 7, and 8 (when it is released).